# FTP LIST: Why does Chrome use the non-standard "LIST -l"?

Tags: google-chrome, ftp

The FTP specification [RFC959](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) defines the `LIST` command this way:

```
LIST [<SP> <pathname>] <CRLF>
```

I've written an FTP server, but it fails for Chrome because Chrome sends `LIST -l`. My server assumes '-l' to be a filename, because that's what the spec says.

So why does Chrome use `LIST -l`, is there a newer RFC that allows adding arguments to `LIST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vmsnet.networks.tcp-ip.multinet/RZkKt7_1agU):

> a "-L" parameter apparently is widely used in Unix ftp servers to specify symbolic links should be resolved.

So respond with a `50x` to the client, telling your server doesn't understand that parameter. I'm sure Chrome will then retry without `-L`.

Comment: Hm, could be, my server responds to `SYST` with `215 UNIX`. Some clients behave better (esp. with regards to UTF-8) if the server identifies as UNIX.

Comment: Can the `-L` be followed by a path? I have seen so far only `LIST -l`, can there be `LIST -l /`?

Comment: @sashoalm I don't know, it's not standard. You'll have to reverse engineer the most common approach using other servers and clients.